# Unable to comprehend results of principal component analysis

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions, data-analysis

(Image below) Image shows the principal component analysis of two points {(1,3), (3,1)}. u1 and u2 are drawn which are corresponding eigenvectors after PCA. The points follow a normal distribution N(0,0.5^2).

The text says that the eigenvector u1 is associated with both noisy and noise-free signal, while eigenvector u2 is associated with only noise component. I don't understand how u2 is associated with only noise?

[image: PCA]

Comment: it follows a [mixture of 2 Gaussians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model) distribution with same variance but different mean (centroid). what they call the noise-free component is the vector between the two centroids.

Comment: Consider describing vectors in terms of the $(u_1,u_2)$ coordinate system where the origin is now at at $(2,2)$. The coefficient of $u_1$ primarily tells you which mean the vector was drawn from (note that $u_1$ gives the line between the two means). It should be fairly close to $+1$ or $-1$ for a typical sample point. The coefficient of $u_2$ primarily tells you where the noise moved the point to (from its mean).

Comment: The thing is, I already knew that: you *generated* this data by randomly picking a mean and then adding an independent normal, mean zero r.v. to the mean you picked. PCA can let you extract that information from the data itself without knowing where it came from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only piece of information that you need to distinguish between the points $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ is a component in the direction of $u_1$.

In particular: the centroid of our data is $\mu = (2,2)$ (or right around there, anyway).  We can deduce whether a signal $s = (s_1,s_2)$ should be $(1,3)$ or $(3,1)$ by stating that a signal is $(3,1)$ if $(s - \mu)^Tu_1$ is negative, and $(3,1)$ if $(s - \mu)^Tu_1$ is positive.

To that effect, the $u_1$ component of the signal contains all of its informational content.

On the other hand, under ideal setting, $(s - \mu)^Tu_2$ should always be $0$.  The only reason for any deviation from $0$ is noise.  So, we say that the $u_2$ direction is only associated with noise.

Comment: I think "should be..." and "is..." is awkward wording, in your second paragraph. I might instead say "is drawn from a normal distribution with mean ..." or something like that instead. +1 though.